# sending mails to large number of users at same time in minimum amount of time

Tags: php

If i want to send mail notifications to thousands of users at the same time stored in my database, using simple database query to fetch required users where mail has to be sent and then sending mails to all of them simultaneously will take up a lot of time, so what can be the best possible way to do so in minimum time?

Comment: You might want to use providers with APIs for this special purpose, e.g. [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com)

Answer (score 0):

```
    This Solution may help you....

    (1) SET A Cron JOB For Sending E-Mail & Also Maintain a Flag For Those Persons which have you sent the mail. 
    (2) Also Use Ajax API Whicxh will Notify you regarding sent E-mails.

    (3)Steps :  How To Run PHP Script For Using Cron JOB

    Method 1: Execute the script using php from the crontab
    To execute myscript.php every 1 hour do the following:
    # crontab -e
    00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/john/myscript.php

    Method 2: Run the php script using URL from the crontab

    00 * * * * lynx -dump http://www.thegeekstuff.com/myscript.php

    The following script executes the php script (every 5 minutes) by calling the URL using CURL. Curl by default displays the output in the standard output. Using the “curl -o” option, you can also dump the output of your script to a temporary file as shown below.

    */5 * * * * /usr/bin/curl -o temp.txt http://www.thegeekstuff.com/myscript.php

Now You Can Implement Your Code Easily...
```